# Ways to get User Activity Feed from Scribd?

Tags: rss, feed, scribd

I am working with an academic type client. He asked for a webpage with some social network feeds showing on it.  Twitter, Facebook... so far I haven't had problem with these, but it is being a headache to find some way to embed Scribd onto the page. I would like to retrieve information on his documents (date of publication, names...). I can't seem to find some kind of user activity rss feed, a document feed simply stating that kind of data.

Do you know if there is any?

Answer (score 2):

Check with Firebug, something like this:

```
http://www.scribd.com/feeds/user_rss/65135503
```

Answer (score 1):

kant was absolutely correct. I just stumbled across this question as I'm looking to implement a scribd feed into my website; I assume the OP has gone now due to his rep and the length of time ago this was posted.

If anyone is interested though; the URL to the feed is exactly like kant posted:

```
http://www.scribd.com/feeds/user_rss/<your-id-here>
```

To get your ID: Log in to scribd and view the source code of any page, in the head amongst the many  blocks there is one with the User ID - on the page I'm looking at it's on line 91. It looks like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window['$rat'] = ratInit(
            ["http://rs1.scribd.com/","http://rs2.scribd.com/","http://rs3.scribd.com/","http://rs4.scribd.com/","http://rs5.scribd.com/","http://rs6.scribd.com/","http://rs7.scribd.com/","http://rs8.scribd.com/"],
            {"user_id":156281674,"doc_id":null}, //<--- user_id!
            false
    );
</script>
```

Using this you can simply pop the ID into the URL. As an example, my feed would be at http://www.scribd.com/feeds/user_rss/156281674!

Comment: Is this still working? I checked this with my user id. But it says `page not found`?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam That link will *definitely* 404 as I deleted my account; but it does appear that they now have a decent [API](http://www.scribd.com/developers/platform) and this should be possible without any hacks anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I searched many pages and could not find "user_id"

Finally I viewed my profile image in a separate tab and my userid was in the URL for the profile image.

http://imgv2-3.scribdassets.com/img/word_user/213701893/130x140/b05871ff47/1367903128

http://www.scribd.com/feeds/user_rss/213701893